# Detect which SDK Version was used to build a OSX Framework

Tags: macos, frameworks

I need to detect which SDK Version was used to build a OSX Framework.

Any helpful hints would be appreciated
Florian

Comment: You can use `otool -L` to grab the libraries (and versions) that a framework links against. What precisely are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint that solved my problem

I need to validate that a framwework was really built with the 10.6 SDK
Thanks for you hint, I solved the problem with the otool

Using otool -L  prints the the following lines if you link against the 10.6 SDK
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 550.29.0)

If you still use the 10.5 SDK you will get a different current version number 
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 476.19.0)