# How to get the version of iOS SDK that was used to build a static library?

Tags: ios, sdk, static-libraries

I have a third-party static library and I need to know which SDK was used to build it. Other than asking the team that built it, is there any way to get this information.

I know you can [do it for frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976145/400544) but I have not figured out how to use this tool to get the right info for a static library, assuming it's even possible.